# magento custom shipping unable to use Log function

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods, development, log

I would like to know if logging is prohibited in this location?

```
public function getAllowedMethods()
{
    Mage::log("getAllowedMethods", null, "sam.txt");
    return array(
        'standard' => "Standard",
        'custom' => "Custom",
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if your logging is disabled it won't work.
Try to use it like this:

```
Mage::log("getAllowedMethods", null, "sam.txt", true);
```

The last parameter set to `true` forces the log even if logging is disabled.
If in this case nothing is logged then your method is not called.

Comment: may logging is enabled. it's just this particular function which is an interface required for creating custom shipping methods